# posting uploaded file name

Tags: php, file

I want to output the filename. I also want to check the length of the filename. I have tried the following which didn't work.

```
echo $_POST[$_FILES['file']['name']];

echo (strlen($_POST[$_FILES['file']['name']]);
```

Comment: `$_FILES` does not live inside `$_POST`

Comment: `echo $_FILES['file']['name'];` and `echo strlen($_FILES['file']['name']);`

Comment: Beat me to it @RiggsFolly

Comment: A simple `print_r($_POST);` would have easily shown you that

Comment: Lets close this as a TYPO before the vultures get to hear about it

Comment: Oh too late, one has already started to attack the carcass

Comment: It posts 'Array'.

Comment: Do you mean it echos the word `Array`?

Comment: Then do a `print_r($_FILES);` so you can see the structure of the $_FILES array. Sound like you are sending more than one file

Comment: Maybe a good place for you to start would be [The PHP manual pages relating to Uploading Multiple Files](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php)

Comment: There are several browse options for more than one upload. But it should not output array. I want the length of filename of whatever is uploaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't use $_POST for getting  the files, simply use $_FILES to get the uploaded files as

```
echo $_FILES['file']['name'];

echo $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
```

To get the file size use

```
echo $_FILES['file']['size']
```

Comment: Dont you think my comment was clear enough?

Comment: @RiggsFolly In his defence, why didn't you put it as an answer instead?

Comment: @Max Some fruit hangs too low for even me

Comment: @RiggsFolly the first thing is i didn't seen your comment when i posted my answer, and the secon and last one why should not i give it as a answer here. It may be too low for you to answer, but not for everyone

Comment: It gives me Array.

Comment: @J.Doe are u uploading multiple files, in multiple file upload you will get an array

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

```
 echo $_FILES['file']['name'][0];
```

Comment: What about `echo $_FILES['file']['name'][1];` and ......

Comment: I only need to know if something is uploaded. What I need to know is actually if anything is added to the first array. Like the following: if(strlen($_FILES['file']['name'][0] > 1)){True/False}